# nomencl glossary, no desription, just endless dots

Tags: nomencl

I'm having a problem with my glossary using the `nomencl` package. As you can see, there is no description, just endless dots... Anyone with the same issue?

[image: nomencl just dots example]

I followed the example here: http://strobelstefan.org/?p=153

Header File:

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\let\abbrev\nomenclature    

\renewcommand{\nomname}{Glossar und Abkürzungsverzeichnis}

\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.25\hsize}

\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}

\makenomenclature
```

Example chapter:

```
\nomenclature{CID}{Description}%
\nomenclature{DTM}{Description}%
\nomenclature{FDT}{Description}%
\nomenclature{SDD}{Description}%
```

Table of contents:

```
\printnomenclature

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossar und Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
```

Comment: Please provide your document,not just a link.

Comment: Welcome! Please help us to help you and provide a minimal working example with fully compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}`, ending with `\end{document}` and in between the code illustrating your problem. It doesn't make fun to build a compilable LaTex file from given code snippets.

Comment: Glueing fragments together is not my hobby!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

Assuming, the document is called `foo.tex`, use

```
makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o foo.nls foo.nlo 
pdflatex foo
```

after compilation. The `foo.nlo` file is generated during the `LaTeX` compilation, the real nomenclature file is `foo.nls`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\let\abbrev\nomenclature    

\renewcommand{\nomname}{Glossar und Abkürzungsverzeichnis}

\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.25\hsize}

\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}

\makenomenclature



\nomenclature{CID}{Description}%
\nomenclature{DTM}{Description}%
\nomenclature{FDT}{Description}%
\nomenclature{SDD}{Description}%


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\printnomenclature

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossar und Abkürzungsverzeichnis}

\end{document}
```

[image]